# Probability and statistics involving infinite series.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

For a certain discrete random variable on the non-negative integers, the probability function satisfies the relationship $P(0)=P(1)$ and $P(k+1)={1\over k}P(k)$ for $k=1,2,3,\dots$ find $P(0)$.

Immediately looking at this I can see P(2)=P(1)=P(0) and P(3)=(1/2)P(2) and P(4)=(1/6)P(2) and P(k+1)= (1/(k!))P(2). But I'm still not sure how to approach this.

Comment: What are $p$ and $P$?

Comment: Sorry no lower case. P(x) is equivalent to the probability of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing out the first few terms:

$$P(2) = P(1) = P(0);$$

$$P(3) = (1/2)P(2) = (1/2)P(1) = (1/2)P(0);$$

$$P(4) = (1/3)P(3) = (1/3!)P(0);$$

$$P(5) = (1/4)P(4) = (1/4!)P(0).$$

So the sum of all of these must add up to $1$.  Since $0! = 1! = 1$:

$$P(0) + (1/0!)P(0) + (1/1!)P(0) + (1/2!)P(0) + (1/3!)P(0) + ... = P(0)(1 + e) = 1.$$

So $$P(0) = (1+e)^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$P(0) = \frac{1}{(1+e)}$.

Infinite series equals $1$ (sum of probabilities). Using hint and a little algebra gives answer.